# LeetCode 845. Longest Mountain in Array

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-mountain-in-array/
Heres my Code

```
class Solution:    
def longestMountain(self, arr: List[int]) -> int:
        direction = 1
        curLength = 0
        longest = 0
        
        if len(arr) < 3:
            return 0
        
        for i in range(1,len(arr)):
            cur = arr[i]
            prev = arr[i -1]
            
            if direction == 1:
                if cur > prev:
                    curLength += 1 if curLength > 0 else 2
                elif cur < prev:
                    direction = -1
                    curLength += 1
                    longest = max(longest,curLength)
                elif cur == prev:
                    curLength = 0
                    
            elif direction == -1:
                if cur > prev:
                    direction = 1
                    curLength += 1
                elif cur < prev:
                    curLength += 1
                    longest = max(longest, curLength)
                elif cur == prev:
                    direction = 1
                    curLength = 0
        return longest
```

It seems like it won't pass all the use case,for example[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,] should be 0 mountains, but my code outputted 9, I simply fix it by changing it range((2,len(arr))

Then it wouldn't pass the the testcase[0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on how to ask a question. Your post does not include one.

Comment: Try troubleshooting some more to create a minimal, reproducible example of the issue you are having

Comment: It is not a result of a simple mistake - the approach has a fundamental flaw. Sometimes explaining the intent behind the code (or, even better, before writing the code) helps to see it yourself

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a possible solution:

```
N = len(arr)
ans = base = 0

while base < N:
    end = base
    if end + 1 < N and arr[end] < arr[end + 1]:
        while end+1 < N and arr[end] < arr[end+1]:
            end += 1
        if end + 1 < N and arr[end] > arr[end + 1]:
            while end+1 < N and arr[end] > arr[end+1]:
                end += 1
            ans = max(ans, end - base + 1)
    base = max(end, base + 1)
return ans
```